# WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'wss://enabler.sustent.in/ws' failed:

Tags: reactjs, websocket, lets-encrypt

I am getting this warning in my console, ever since I applied Let's Encrypt SSL to my react nodejs project hosted on AWS. Is SSL configuration a problem? Thing is, I have not used socket connection code anywhere in my project.
I've added WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0 to my react env file but even this is not solving the issue.
Please guide me to where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall settings in AWS could potentially block WebSocket connections. If your security group rules or network ACLs do not allow connections on the port you're trying to use, this could result in a failure.

Could you check both port 80 for non-secure connections (ws://) and port 443 for secure connections (wss://)?